# How to attach new data disks to an existing Azure Virtual Machine using ARM template

Tags: azure

I would like to know how to attach new data disks to an existing Azure VM using an ARM template.

I do not want to create a new VM and this is what the current documentation shows. If omit information like the hardwareProfile and networkProfile, the template is not considered valid.

A satisfactory answer shows the json template for attaching two new data disks to an existing VM without having to provide auxillary information about the vm.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, you can't attach a data disk to a VM through an ARM template, however you can accomplish that through PowerShell ARM Cmdlet as below

```
$VirtualMachine = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup11" -Name "VirtualMachine07"
Add-AzureRmVMDataDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -Name "disk1" -VhdUri "URL to VHD file" -LUN 0 -Caching ReadOnly -DiskSizeinGB 1 -CreateOption Empty
Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup11" -Name "VirtualMachine07" -VM $VirtualMachine
```

Comment: is that still true?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander now you can do it using resource manager ARM template https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/using-managed-disks-template-deployments